How to use a Rust data type with an extra field?
I have a bunch of geo::Geometry objects which I need to contain and get the total bounding_rect of. The obvious way to do this is to use GeometryCollection. So far so good.
However, each of my geometries also has a name string, which it’s impossible to store in the normal Geometry struct. If I compose a new struct to store the Geometry and its name together, then I no longer have a Geometry, so I can’t store the structure in a GeometryCollection and can’t get the bounding_rect.
How can I solve this? I see two approaches, but neither feels very clean:

Compose a MyGeometryCollection struct and store the names in a parallel Vec. Then, I guess, iterate them together as needed.
Create the above struct, but also MyGeometey to store the name. Keep a Vec of these in MyGeometryCollection. When it comes time to get the bounding_rect, create the GeometryCollection on the fly o to call the appropriate method on it. This will involve first creating a Vec of the geom fields of each instantiated MyGeometry structure.

Are there any other options I’m missing?

Third option, since GeometryCollection simply contains pub Vec<Geometry<T>>, then your MyGeometryCollection could also simply contain GeometryCollection and Vec<String>. Then you can iter zip the two Vecs, to get the Geometry and the String name

Thanks for the quick reply! This is what I was attempting to describe as option 1 from my list. Coming from OOP, it feels weird/fragile to have a parallel list where the fields are associated via an index. But maybe this is just more accepted in Rust land? Not weird in an RDBMS context, TBH.

Oh, I somehow completely overlooked the "store the names in parallel Vec" part. Anyways, the new type idiom is quite prevalent in Rust. So as long as your MyGeometryCollection, or, let's rename it NamedGeometryCollection. As long it it's self contained, and this is the ONLY thing it does. Then it should be stable. Overall, you likely only need to juggle a few push(), remove(), etc methods, along with some utils forwarded to GeometryCollection

Whether it's the best approach depends on overall what your goal is of course. Looking at the docs, the bounding_rect() method is part of a BoundingRect trait. So a NamedGeomtry could also easily impl BoundingRect for NamedGeometry and delegate to the inner Geometry's bounding_rect()

One of the variants of Geometry contains a GeometryCollection. Do you need the sub-geometries in that collection to be named as well?
